# How to expand a given string of a range of an of an interval of positive numbers to a list?

Tags: python

For example, given a string list like `'1-3,8-12,17',` I want it to return something like `[1,2,3,8,9,10,11,12,17]`. Fairly new to python so I'm not even sure how to begin.

Comment: "split" method of strings can help here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems.
"I'm not even sure how to begin" is not a specific problem; it's a request for tutoring, which is out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Would "split" work with strings?

Comment: [split() is a string method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) so yes, it works with strings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not beautiful code, but here it is:

```
import numpy as np

np.concatenate([np.arange(int(x[0]), int(x[-1]) + 1) 
                for x in [i.split('-') for i in a.split(',')]])
```

```
Out[104]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 17])
```

Since you said you're very new to Python, I'll give you a little bit of info. This solution uses *a)* list comprehension, *b)* `str.split()` function, *c)* `numpy.arange()`, and *d)* `numpy.concatenate()`.

Comment: Since farhan states to be new to python: if numpy is not installed, you can get it with `python -m pip install numpy --user`.

Comment: @WimLavrijsen: Frankly, for anyone new to Python, the answer should not involve stuff like `numpy` in the first place. They barely understand regular Python, and you're introducing a massively heavyweight library that's of only tangential relevance to the problem at hand.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: it's not me introducing numpy: my answer is the other one which does not use extra modules. :) I just thought it useful to add how to get numpy if farhan wants to run Nicolas' answer, as it's needed for that code. To farhan: yes, numpy is big and will take up about 40MB of disk space (20MB installation, 20MB cache). It's generally useful, but if you want to remove it, run `python -m pip uninstall numpy`, and clean out the cache (is in `~/.cache/pip` if on linux).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the posted example is the only format, this code will do it:

```
def str2range(instr):
   out = list()
   for r in instr.split(','):
       r = r.split('-')
       if len(r) == 2:
           out += range(int(r[0]), int(r[1])+1)
       elif len(r) == 1:
           out.append(int(r[0]))
   return out
```

Comment: You forgot `import numpy as np`, though, which would make it two lines. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially the same as [Nicolas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59061533/364696), but without resorting to heavyweight third party packages like `numpy`:

```
from itertools import chain

a = '1-3,8-12,17'

print(list(chain.from_iterable(range(int(x[0]), int(x[-1])+1)
                               for x in (s.split('-') for s in a.split(',')))))
```

Mind you, for someone new to Python, this is so much gibberish, so an expanded, more direct form with simpler tools is just:

```
def str2range(a):
    res = []
    for mayberange in a.split(','):
         start, sep, end = mayberange.partition('-')
         start = int(start)
         if sep:  # Tests if - appears in string at all; if it doesn't, both sep and end are empty string
             # We have a range; parse the end, and insert all values in the range
             res += range(start, int(end) + 1)
         else:
             # Only a single value, append it by itself
             res.append(start)
    return res
```

To be clear, this second solution is roughly the same as Wim's; I find `str.partition` a superior option when we know we want either exactly one split, or no split, as it lets us unpack to meaningful names (the result is always a three-`tuple`), and provides a cheaper way to test whether a split occurred (even cheaper than `len` testing). But Wim's solution is perfectly fine (I up-voted it).